# heroku trying to deploy a minibrowser

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy an app on heroku through github and getting this error log everytime.

> {  2019-10-22T04:46:56.976381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>       2019-10-22T04:46:56.913376+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
>       2019-10-22T04:46:56.923746+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>       2019-10-22T04:46:56.924056+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>       2019-10-22T04:46:56.924182+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-22T04_46_56_915Z-debug.log
>       2019-10-22T04:46:57.14468+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>       2019-10-22T04:46:57.148344+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>         2019-10-22T11:57:15.000755+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
>       2019-10-22T11:57:15.010793+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>       2019-10-22T11:57:15.014646+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>       2019-10-22T11:57:15.015382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-22T11_57_15_002Z-debug.log
>       2019-10-22T11:57:17.209791+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com }>

this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "min",
  "productName": "Min",
  "author": "PalmerAL",
  "version": "1.11.1",
  "description": "A fast, minimal browser that protects your privacy",
  "electronVersion": "6.0.2",
  "main": "main.build.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "dexie": "^1.2.0",
    "dragula": "^3.6.2",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "mousetrap": "^1.5.3",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.0.943",
    "string_score": "^0.1.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "archiver": "^3.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.2.2",
    "chokidar": "^2.0.4",
    "decomment": "^0.9.0",
    "electron": "^6.0.2",
    "electron-installer-redhat": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-installer-windows": "^1.1.1",
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.4",
    "electron-renderify": "0.0.2",
    "standard": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "electron-installer-debian": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/standard --verbose js/**/*.js main/*.js",
    "watch": "node ./scripts/watch.js",
    "buildMain": "node ./scripts/buildMain.js",
    "buildBrowser": "node ./scripts/buildBrowser.js",
    "buildPreload": "node ./scripts/buildPreload.js",
    "build": "npm run buildMain && npm run buildBrowser && npm run buildPreload",
    "buildWindows": "npm run build && node ./scripts/buildWindows.js",
    "buildMac": "npm run build && node ./scripts/buildMac.js",
    "buildDebian": "npm run build && node ./scripts/buildDebian.js",
    "buildRedhat": "npm run build && node ./scripts/buildRedhat.js",
    "buildAll": "npm run buildWindows && npm run buildMac && npm run buildDebian && npm run buildRedhat",
    "updateFilters": "node ./ext/filterLists/updateEasylist.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/minbrowser/min.git"
  }
}
```

if someone would help me that would be really  appreciated

****New error code****
    2019-10-22T21:58:53.757481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
    2019-10-22T21:58:53.786108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
    2019-10-22T21:58:53.913021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
    2019-10-22T21:58:53.966524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-10-22T21:58:54.33422+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com request_id=e5037711-4e60-4bf6-921c-8edf6e2bff03 fwd="71.201.83.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2019-10-22T21:58:55.387616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com request_id=256dfa93-0362-487f-b809-f9d476f5524c fwd="71.201.83.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2019-10-22T21:58:56.692461+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=browserbyfazal.herokuapp.com request_id=c118698d-3fd7-4cec-86b7-cbf51bcf3cc7 fwd="71.201.83.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: didnt meant cool greatly appreciated, also this whole stuff is new to me, it would be great if it is simple.

Comment: It says missing start script. Have you added start script in your package.json file?

Comment: how do i do that? i mean i have tried before but i cant find my entry point

Comment: Add these two in your package.json file 
   "scripts": {
    "start": "node <your_main_file>.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "<your node version>"
  },

Comment: @Osama I  have done this and and no change I have done what ragu said and now it starts up loads for one minute and crashes and shows error which i put at the bottom of the post. Please help! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Please add start script in your package.json

please refer [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)

Inside the scripts in package.json try adding

```
"scripts": {
        "start":"npm start",
        ... //Ur previous scripts
    },
```

Comment: I have done what you said and now I can load in my app but will crash after sometime and give an error in the log. please check the bottom code of my post for error . Thank you for the code and any help.

Comment: I could see there is some difference in the $PORT thats why it is failing. May i know what port are you using?